# Нужно написать программу выводящую всевозможные строки подходящие по условию

Tags: python

> Условие:
>
> - Строка стоит из 6 букв
> - 1 и 4 буквы одинаковы
> - Все остальные буквы должны быть уникальными и не повторятся между собой
> - Только английские буквы

Строка должна выглядеть примерно так "abcade"
Сижу уже часа три мучаюсь, не могу понять как это реализовать.
Программу желательно написать на питоне, но можно и на любом другом языке, думаю дальше сам разберусь

Comment: И что именно не получается? если найти того, кто ЗА ВАС напишет программу - так Вы форумом ошиблись... А если что-то конкретное - так это "конкретное" и надо спрашивать.

Comment: Здравствуйте на Stack Overflow на русском! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: @Akina как я вижу нашлось аж 4 желающих написать программу за автора

Comment: @whizz169 Лёгкая репа...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import itertools
import string

for p in itertools.permutations(string.ascii_lowercase, 5):
    print(f'{p[0]}{p[1]}{p[2]}{p[0]}{p[3]}{p[4]}')
```

Answer (score 5):

Вроде так

```
from itertools import permutations
import string
for p in permutations(string.ascii_lowercase, 4):
    for l in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if l not in p:
            print(l + p[0] + p[1] + l + p[2] + p[3])
```

https://ideone.com/b4Xpw5

Comment: Так быстрее, чем у меня в ответе, так что лучше использовать этот вариант

Answer (score 2):

Вот так вот в лоб, но работать будет медленнее, чем перебор 5 символов, хотя печать лучше делать 1 раз:

```
import itertools, string

res = {p[:3] + tuple(p[0]) + p[4:] for p in itertools.permutations(string.ascii_lowercase, 6)}

print(res)
```

Comment: Да, тут придется ждать, пока не будут получены все результаты

Comment: @MaxLevs проблема не в печати, печать 1 раз как раз самая быстрая. Проблема в переборе 6 символов, когда можно 5

Comment: я не про печать говорил

Answer (score 1):

Знаю, что мой код не самый лучший. Тот, до которого додумался. У меня работал 20 минут: 10 на обработку, 10 на вывод (результатов куча).

```
chars = [chr(x) for x in range(97, 123)]
res = []

def repeatingchars(s):
    c = 0
    for char in s:
        c += s.count(char)
    return c != len(s)

for c1 in chars:
    for c2 in chars:
        for c3 in chars:
            for c4 in chars:
                for c5 in chars:
                    for c6 in chars:
                        s = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6
                        if s[0] == s[3] and not repeatingchars(s[1:3] + s[4:]):
                            res.append(s)

for word in res:
    print(word)
print("Results:", len(res))
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код